# qml desktop components scaling

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I want to create a user interface qtquick2 that can be scaled and includes some desktop components. As mentioned in this [blogpost](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2012/08/08/native-looking-text-in-qml-2) the default rendering for qml/qtquick2 should use distance fields and not native text rendering. I tried to scale qt quick controls. The result is rather disappointing. I was testing on ubuntu 64 and qt-5.1.1. The text on the controls is looking bad but all text in standard qml elements (Text/TextEdit) is looking good when scaled.

This leads me to think that native rendering is the default now for desktop components. Can this be turned of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting render types of Qt Quick Controls will be available in Qt 5.2 using styles, e.g. in `TextArea`:

```
TextArea {
    /* ... */
    style: TextAreaStyle {
        renderType: Text.QtRendering
    }
}
```

Supported render types are:

- `Text.QtRendering`
- `Text.NativeRendering` (default)

See [TextArea.qml](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtquickcontrols/source/11cf03da797456e9f5714d8a5a8e1cc727ba2086%3asrc/controls/TextArea.qml), [TextAreaStyle.qml](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtquickcontrols/source/11cf03da797456e9f5714d8a5a8e1cc727ba2086%3asrc/controls/Styles/Base/TextAreaStyle.qml).

For `Button` and `ButtonStyle` there is no public interface to set the render type directly in Qt 5.2. But what you can do, is overwrite the `label` with your own text component:

```
Button {
    id: theButton
    /* ... */
    style: ButtonStyle {
        label: Item {
        implicitWidth: row.implicitWidth
        implicitHeight: row.implicitHeight

        property var __syspal: SystemPalette {
            colorGroup: theButton.enabled ?
                        SystemPalette.Active : SystemPalette.Disabled
        }

        Row {
            id: row
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            spacing: 2
            Image {
                source: theButton.iconSource
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            }
            Text {
                renderType: Text.NativeRendering /* Change me */
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                text: theButton.text
                color: __syspal.text
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code is inspired by the default `label` component of [ButtonStyle.qml](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtquickcontrols/source/11cf03da797456e9f5714d8a5a8e1cc727ba2086%3asrc/controls/Styles/Base/ButtonStyle.qml), modified and untested.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can change text rendering in Qt Components since they are explicitly made for the use in desktop applications.

In [TextArea](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquickcontrols/qml-qtquick-controls1-textarea.html) for example there is no `renderType` like in [TextEdit](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-textedit.html#renderType-prop).

On the [QtDesktopComponents](http://qt-project.org/wiki/QtDesktopComponents) page I another hint:

> You have to change QGuiApplication to a QApplication. This is because the components rely on certain widget-specific classes such as QStyle to do native rendering.

Comment: thank you for your response. The only thing that makes me think that the text rendering could use distance fields is that it is used as a example to explain it in the blog. Perhaps this was a feature in the begining of QtDesktopComponents and got lost while adding support for Styling. Perhaps I'll try an old version from git and see if it fits my needs better.