# Scaling and positioning in QML

Tags: qt, resize, qml, qt5, scaling

I'm developing a Qt5.11.1 QML application that runs into a `QQuickWidget`. The resize mode is set to `SizeRootObjectToView`. Hence, whenever I resize the `QMainWindow` I see my QML root object that scales too.

Inside I have some images anchored to fill the parent, and they are scaled as expected. Instead I have issues with smaller images or text that should maintain the same relative position and size.

I begin with absolute position and size when ratio is 1:1. Example: the root item has a size of 1920x1080 px, and I must place the other items (mainly images and texts) to given coordinates.

When the root changes its size all the elements should follow it. I tried this:

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Rectangle {
    id: root
    visible: true
    color: "black"

    property real ratio: root.width / 1920

    readonly property real x_CenterGauge: 502
    readonly property real y_CenterGauge: 489

    Image {
        x: x_CenterGauge * ratio
        y: y_CenterGauge * ratio
        scale: ratio
    }
}
```

but this doesn't work because the `root.width` property (and in turn `ratio`) doesn't change when I resize the window. But it actually resize the root element because any anchored item will resize too! I get a change only if I maximize/minimize the window.

I read [this article](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/scalability.html) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20311318/qml-desktop-components-scaling), but I still don't understand how to handle the resising in QML.

Comment: what is `Image1`? Some custom item? typo? what is `root`?  Please provide _all_ appropriate source. Try to add `onRatioChanged` handler to see the value changes.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. It's a standard `Image`.

Comment: As said, `ratio` doesn't change (i.e. `onRatioChanged`) is not called when resizing the window with the lower-right corner. Only when I maximize or minimize it.

Comment: I've tested the code and it works well for me. It looks that you do something wrong, please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can run and test it. Anyway, I advice you to use `Layout` instead of custom positioning.

Comment: I cannot use a `Layout` because need to position items on a background image, so I have to exactly place them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In testing it is the property scale that seems to be a problem
By modifying width and height instead it solves the problem

```
Rectangle {
    id: root
    visible: true
    color: "black"

    property real ratio: root.width / 1920

    readonly property real x_CenterGauge: 202
    readonly property real y_CenterGauge: 489

    Image {
        x: root.x_CenterGauge * root.ratio
        y: root.y_CenterGauge * root.ratio

        width: implicitWidth * root.ratio
        height: implicitHeight * root.ratio
        //scale: ratio
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct. It is intentional that scale property doesn't actually change size of element. It's very helpful when dealing with animations.